Unit test with nunit and MOQ
 var note = await _dbContext.Notes
    .Where(n => n.IntNoteId == ReferenceAsInteger)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

how can use MOQ setup this to make it work ?

What have you tried? Where are you having problems? Please edit the post so that it supplies a minimal reproducible example.

See docs

Mock out the _dbContext and inject it into your Software Under Test. Make the mock return a list of Notes, one of which should have the IntNoteId that matches your reference.
var mock = new Mock<DbContext>();

// Create a list of Notes, one of which has the right reference

mock.SetupGet(m => m.Notes)
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(myListOfNotes));

// initialize your software under test, injecting mock.Object

var result = await myClass.GetNote(referenceAsInteger);

// or whatever it is you want to do.

